# Draggable google map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, draggable

I have been working with google maps and now have a requirement to make a draggable marker that I can place on the map.

Is this a big difference in complexity from just placing markers by geolocation coordinates?  What is the best way of going about making draggable markers that users can set?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont mention which version of the API you are using, so i will asume v3... There is a draggable property that you can either set in the constructor using the options parameter 'draggable: true' or by invoking the setDraggable(true) function after it is created.

Check http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker for more info.

Edit: For version 2 there are enableDragging() and disableDragging() functions...

As for adding markers, perhaps subscribe to the mouse click event on the map, and then add a marker in there. The coordinates are passed into the event handling function as part of the event parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        function geocodePosition(pos) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                latLng: pos
            }, function (responses) {
                if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                    updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
                } else {
                    updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
                }
            });
        }

        function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
            document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
        }

        function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
                latLng.lat(),
                latLng.lng()
            ].join(', ');
        }

        function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
            document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
        }

        function initialize() {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(9.010951935679284, 38.760017580032354);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                title: 'Point A',
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });

            // Update current position info.
            updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
            geocodePosition(latLng);

            // Add dragging event listeners.
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function () {
                updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
                updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
                updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
                updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
                geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
            });
        }

        // Onload handler to fire off the app.
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
        #mapCanvas {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            float: left;
        }

        #infoPanel {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

            #infoPanel div {
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
    </style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
    <div id="infoPanel">
        <b>Marker status:</b>
        <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
        <b>Current position:</b>
        <div id="info"></div>
        <b>Closest matching address:</b>
        <div id="address"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?